# Hashing a Password and Saving to application.yaml (Spring Boot 2.7.3)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

My objective is to hash a password that is passed from the command line argument and save it to the `application.yaml`. Then when the user authenticates using the password to match it and allow users in.

I am passing the value like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--user.password=admin"
```

The fragment of the security section in `application.yaml` looks like this:

```
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: ${user.password}
```

I have written some password encoder classes in my spring boot application.

```
class MyPasswordEncoder : PasswordEncoder {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val argon2PasswordEncoder = Argon2PasswordEncoder(SALT_LENGTH, HASH_LENGTH, PARALLELISM, MEMORY_USE, ITERATIONS)

    /**
     * Encrypt the password (Algorithm Used: Argon2id)
     */
    override fun encode(decryptedPassword: CharSequence?): String {

        val hashedPassword : String = argon2PasswordEncoder.encode(decryptedPassword)

        logger.debug("Password Encoding Successful!")

        return hashedPassword
    }


    /**
     * Matches the password with the encoded password (Algorithm Used: Argon2id)
     */
    override fun matches(rawPassword: CharSequence?, encodedPassword: String?): Boolean {
        return argon2PasswordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)
    }
}
```

And the Delegation class:

```
class MyPasswordDelegation {

fun createDelegatingPasswordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {

    val idForEncode = "myEncoder"
    val encoders: MutableMap<String, PasswordEncoder> = mutableMapOf()

    encoders[idForEncode] = NCaaSPasswordEncoder()

    return DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders)
}
```

}

My Security Config class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("\${spring.security.user.name}")
    private val userName: String? = null

    @Value("\${spring.security.user.password}")
    private val password: String? = null

    @Autowired
    lateinit var appAuthenticationEntryPoint: AppAuthenticationEntryPoint


    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): MyPasswordEncoder {
        return MyPasswordEncoder()
    }


    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun userDetailsService(): InMemoryUserDetailsManager? {

        val userDetails : UserDetails = User.withUsername(userName).password(passwordEncoder().encode(password).roles("USER").build()

        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails)
    }


    @Throws(Exception::class)
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(httpSecurity : HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()

        // Allow only HTTPS Requests
        httpSecurity.requiresChannel {
                channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure()
        }.authorizeRequests {
                authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(appAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        }

        return httpSecurity.build()
    }
}
```

But when I try to authenticate using `admin/admin`, I get the following error:

```
Failed to process authentication request
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:172)
```

I know I am going wrong somewhere. But since this is all new to me, I am not able to quite put it all together.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is the third time within a day you are asking the same question, please don't. Duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344624/unable-to-externalize-property-from-command-line-spring-boot-2-3-7) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344624/unable-to-externalize-property-from-command-line-spring-boot-2-3-7/74345456#74345456)

Comment: @M.Deinum That was something different to be honest. I wasn't able to pass it as a parameter. Yes, they do look similar, I admit!